# How does Ansible treat tasks when serial parameter is more than one?

Tags: ansible

When the `serial` parameter is 1, Ansible takes a host and then executes the tasks given in the playbook before moving onto the next host.

But what happens when `serial` parameter is more than one?

For example, if I have 10 hosts and my serial parameter is 3, **how will those 3 tasks execute the tasks?** **Will those tasks be executed one after another one host at a time?** Or will it be executed like the default execution strategy, **each host will execute the first task before moving on the next one.**

I haven't found any documentation that refers to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the assumption you keep the standard [strategy](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/user_guide/playbooks_strategies.html), each play of the playbook will be executed on as many nodes as you specified on the keyword `serial`, but task by task, so even if you have a node that run a task faster than the others node, It won't run the next task, until the others have finished the same task. Then another 3 nodes will be taken from the inventory. If you have another play, the same scenario will be done.

so basically with your 10 nodes inventory that will do

- take 3 nodes
- execute tasks
- take 3 nodes
- execute tasks
- take 3 nodes
- execute tasks
- take remaining node
- execute tasks

The behaviour is explained in https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/user_guide/playbooks_strategies.html

> *The serial directive can ‘batch’ this behaviour to a subset of the
>   hosts, which then run to completion of the play before the next
>   ‘batch’ starts.*

I suggest you to have such test playbook to play with to understand `playbook`, `plays` and `serial`.

```
- hosts: all         
  gather_facts: false
  serial: 3          
  tasks:             

    - ping:          
    - ping:          

- hosts: all         
  gather_facts: false
  serial: 5 # test with 5 nodes now          
  tasks:             

    - ping:          
    - ping:
```

if you want to simulate the difference of behaviour, you can run your playbook with the option `-C`